# Win 10 Format vs Delete Partition

Tags: windows, windows-10, data-recovery, veracrypt, recovery

I wanted to know what's the difference between `Delete` and `Format` on the Windows 10 Setup. I accidentally deleted a drive there and I want to know if this is better or worse than format in terms of data recovery.

The part I'm talking about is this one image:

[image: Windows 10 Setup]

Okay so far I have dd cloned the drive on a .img file, I loaded that file on a another ssd same size and played around on it, first with that drive on windows I allocated that space as RAW, with no drive letter and veracrypt was able to restore its backup volume headers itself but the drives when mounted showed as RAW and coudnt access saying need to format,  after that I tried on Linux and with DMDE was able to recover first partition (Linux Encrypted /home dir) then made another partition with all defaults then with veracrypt mounting I got error:

"mount: media/veracrypt1: wrong fs type, bad option, badsuperblock on /dev/mapper/veracrypt1"

I also tried manually finding backup volume headers that veracrypt has on last sector -256 and did found them but still same error with them also I dont know if its a wrong fs type as in Fat or NTFS or its requiring the partiton to be RAW or something as I read on docs here [Documantion VeraCrypt](https://www.terabyteunlimited.com/kb/article.php?id=462&action=print) the admin on Vera said that it might be something about overwritting hidden volume, but I dont think such thing happend as only partitions were deleted[The Thread mentioned](https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/technical/thread/8b9a0636/?limit=25#ee10) but I dont think this is the case because I get the error on hidden as well on outer. I dont know what to do to pass that error or whats causing it.

Update: Everything fixed and restored, the error I was getting before was because of drive format I guess as it was gpt and my old drive was dos so after switching to dos everything worked, If you encounter same issue as me that u delete partitions dont worry you can restore everything and prob much easier than me because my situation was more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you did was really just deleting partitions, you are in luck. Deleting a single partition is trivial to fix, just re-create it in place. Not with Windows tools though, they are too high-level. Instead, use Linux tools like `fdisk`. Fundamentally, a partition is just an entry in a table with start and end points (and some other stuff).

Restoring multiple partitions is harder (unless you remember sizes down to the byte), but still very much possible if they contained popular filesystems (like NTFS, FAT32, ext2/3/4, …). [Testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) can find many types of popular filesystems. This works by scanning the likely areas or the whole disk (so it can take a very long time) to discover the beginning of filesystems. Most filesystems record in their metadata their size, further easing recovery.

Backing up your drive prior to any recovery attempt is prudent. However, most “consumer” image software will only operate on partitions, not drives. Instead, use `dd` (a Linux/Unix tool) to create a full exact copy of the drive. This requires as much space as the drive has. `dd` is very easy to use.

First, use `fdisk` to identify the drive to back up:

```
daniel@vmx:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for daniel:
Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: Micron_1100_MTFD
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5294E22E-B1FF-429E-B6D6-BB6F7BC4D343

Device         Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048       4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2       4096     266239    262144   128M Linux RAID
/dev/sda3     266240    8654847   8388608     4G Linux swap
/dev/sda4    8654848  113512447 104857600    50G Linux RAID
/dev/sda5  113512448  155455487  41943040    20G Linux RAID
/dev/sda6  155455488 1000215182 844759695 402.8G FreeBSD ZFS

Disk /dev/md1: 50 GiB, 53653536768 bytes, 104792064 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Here, `/dev/md1` does not have any partitions. It could be your source drive! Drive names may vary. `md1` is a RAID volume. `sda` is a physical SATA drive. NVMe drives have distinct names, too.

Then, create a backup: `dd if=/dev/md1 of=/path/to/image.img bs=1M status=progress` (If your version of `dd` does not support `status=progress`, you can just remove it. You won’t see anything while `dd` is running then though.)

You can create the backup anywhere. If you have another drive that is the exact same size as the source, you can also clone the drive (somewhat like `dd if=/dev/md1 of=/dev/sdx …`), but take extra care not to accidentally overwrite the wrong drive! If you have another storage location with enough free space, you can just store the backup in a file (as described above).

You can use virtually any live Linux (Ubuntu, …) because they all contain tools like `dd` and `fdisk`. You’ll have to download Testdisk, but that’s it.

**Update (updated )**: You mention the second partition was encrypted using VeraCrypt. This makes recovery more challenging. Testdisk cannot find partition boundaries with VeraCrypt, only with older TrueCrypt volumes. You’ll have to do everything by hand.

To begin, you have to recover the first partition successfully. You need to know its size. Once the first partition is recovered (and visible in `fdisk -l`), you can proceed.

Chances are, the second partition was right after the first. Run `fdisk /dev/sdX` (or `fdisk /path/to/image`) to operate on the drive/image. Create a new partition:

- Enter `n` (new partition)
- Accept all defaults for:

  - Partition number
  - First sector
  - Last sector
- Optionally check the result with `p` (print)
- Enter `w` (write)

The partition type does not matter for the moment.

Try to mount it using VeraCrypt. If it works, great! If it doesn’t, back to `fdisk`. Delete the second partition, use `d` (delete). Then, create it again with a different first sector and try again.

Comment: Okay so yeah all I did I think was delete them and I disconnected the ssd to dont do anything that might harm it more, there were two partitiosn I guess Its impossible to remeber down to the bytes how much, to do your procedure the dd command woud creating a live bootable linux usb be enough and from there run those commands to cloen the disk? also can the clone be saved on a external drive that I have?

Comment: The drive I wanna restore was linux also and the partitions were ext4 and fat32 I think, also for dd command is it required to have a second drive exact same size or it can be done like on a external hard drive ?

Comment: later on I can restore it with that file if anything goes wrong right? is it better to find a second ssd and after backingup work on second ssd so the orginal remain untouched?

Comment: My disk dosnt show like yours the md1, it has dev/sdc and disklabel type: gpt

Comment: Is this same or does this change things also on backup path why you did image.img the backup extension is .img right?

Comment: Im done with backup of drive, also I didnt mention the drive was encrypted with veracypt is the procedure to backup same or need to do something different, as I saw on a veracrypt forum somone suggested doing sector by sector method. Now I shout get testdisk and scan the whole disk?

Comment: Only the second partition was crypted with veracrypt I read that I need to find volume headers and then recovering will be easy, With the image I created I can turn the drive to state 0 100% same if I mess up right? So if I fail myself to send it to service or something?

Comment: I thought also can I load my backup the .img file to another ssd of same size? as I dont wanna touch the orginal drive for now? or I have to dd it again and clone the drive?

Comment: Okay I cloned another ssd from the .img file I saved previously. Now how do I do it by hand as u mentioned? u meant physiclly lol or like find sectors manually one by one but how do I do that by a software or something else?

Comment: i ran DMDE and it found the Linux partition that I had on a very good state as I see everything shows as it was before all folder names but second drive is not showing as it was encrypted I guess, It shows disk size of first partitions o now its possible to find second also?

Comment: With the partition size in hand you would then have a rough position of where the second partition starts. Repeat the same process. After I find that what to do? Assign old formats to those sectors ?

Comment: I guess that worked but on veracrypt Im gettin wrong fs type, which I guess is because filesystem is not correct, before I think it was Fat32 assigned on linux mint install,  but when I try to change type on fdisk there isnt a plain FAT32 tehre are w95 Fat32 etc, I tried all fat32 there but still same, what Type do you suggest if any

Comment: Without the precise command/action you made and the exact error response, it is difficult to discern what’s going on. [Update your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1607126/edit) with additional information.

Comment: Im not sure if this is because of filesystem type, Im getting error: " mount: media/veracrypt1: wrong fs type, bad option, badsuperblock on /dev/mapper/veracrypt1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error." Coud still the sectors not be the right one or something got corrupted? Also what I thought is can it be beacuse its a different drive name? orginal drive was maybe /dev/sdb this is /dev/sda maybe veracrypt notices this kinda stuff? Also with restoring a volume header there is shown exactly the bytes that veracrypt volume had.

Comment: You still did not provide the exact command you used. VeraCrypt is also supposed to work without resorting to backup headers or whatever, because the original header is still where it is supposed to be.

Comment: Which command are you refering too? yea I guess the orginal header shoud be there still if the sectors are right.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited the title of your question, because standard delete refers to deleting a file which is less worse than a format. However, deleting a partition is worse than a format.

The difference is:

You have an allocated space called partition, and you can format that in different layouts. Format clears the partition, but delete partition removes the partition alltogether, turning it into unallocated space. If you delete multiple partitions, the new unallocated space will not be segmented. If you want to restore the partition, you have to recreate it. If you want it to be the same size as it was, then it helps to know what it was.

Recovering a formatted drive is easier than recovering a deleted partition. Most software can recover a formatted drive if you don't do anything with it since the format, but a deleted partition may require special tools and skills.

Deleting just one partition, and recreating it is not that hard though.

That said, you are in the Windows Setup screen, and if you go for either format or delete, it seems you do not have any sensitive data on the disk anyway. If you are considering repartitioning the entire drive to make windows use all of the space, the easiest trick is to delete all partitions, and then select the unallocated empty space and just install to that. Windows setup will then create 4 partitions. 1 big partition for your C and 3 for recovery purposes. That is the best practice, but it means you have to have backups before doing this, as the drives will be empty afterwards.

**Take careful notice of the Drive 0 vs Drive 1. Limit yourself to only Drive 0 and leave Drive 1 untouched.**

Comment: First that image is just an example, I already deleted accidentally a ssd (Both it partitions) that it had so I want to know was deleting it worse than format, like does delete overwrite, or I thought maybe delete dosnt format at all just partitions arnt organized, so is my data gone for good or it can be recovered?

Comment: delete is usually worse than format. A format can often be recovered, a partition delete is much harder and requires a specialist.

Comment: Where can I find such specialist online as I cant ship my drive or something related I woud preffer somone to help me virtually

Comment: A specialist will cost money and they need to phisically have the drive in order to do things like replacing controller, use special hardware etc, and not to mention, they are extremely pricey. Unless your world will fall apart without the data and you would pay anything, consider the data gone.

Comment: “Recovering a formatted drive is easier than recovering a deleted partition.” – I would like to very much dispute that claim. Simply deleting a partition leads to no data loss whatsoever. Complete recovery is trivial. However, formatting it destroys vital filesystem areas, making recovery so much harder.

Comment: @DanielB thanks for the good news lol can you guys recommand me a good software to clone the drive before I contiune to do anything, a guy is sugessting me testdsik shoud I go with it or get Acronis True Image?

Comment: @DanielB My experience comes with trying to use undelete software which would work on an empty partition (aka formatted) but would not even detect recoverable files if the partition itself was deleted. My experience does come from many years ago, so maybe things have changed. I understand that if you are a recovery expert, the bits are still there even without the partition being there, so that would be easier compared to a full format (not to be mistaken by a quick format)